# how do i set fill color of a svg circle with the help of thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, svg, thymeleaf

I have a SVG image in my html page. I want to fill the circle bacground color using **thymeleaf**. I have tried using inline style tag but it doesnot works and sets the svg circle background color to black.

```html
<svg id="svg" height="50" width="50">
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" stroke="" stroke-width="3" fill="#3f51b5" />
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white"font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" font-size="25px"
alignment-baseline="central" th:value="${results.shortName}">OF</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: You are saying: _I have tried using inline style tag but it doesnot work_ It does!. Please use something like this: `style="fill:red"`

Comment: @AnandYadav Not to beg for points, but if you're problem was solved please accept an answer to let others know that they don't have to look at this question anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @enxaneta. solved it using this

```
<svg id="svg" height="50" width="50">
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" stroke="" stroke-width="3"
th:style="'fill:'+@{${results.borderColor}}+';'" />
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" font-size="25px" alignment-baseline="central" th:text="${results.shortName}">OF</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can do it like this: `th:style="|fill: ${results.borderColor};|"` (just to make it look nicer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with **thymeleaf**, but you can set the fill color of an svg element using an inline style element (or stylesheet) by leaving out the `fill` attribute on the desired element and then using the css `fill` property to set the color:

```html
<svg id="svg" height="50" width="50">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" stroke="" stroke-width="3"/>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white"font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" font-size="25px" alignment-baseline="central" th:value="${results.shortName}">OF</text>
</svg>

<style>
    svg {
        fill: red;
    }
</style>
```